# How do I save the results of my function to a txt file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, variables

I am trying to take data from my quiz and enter it into a txt file using php. This is my quiz code:

```
 function check(){
    var question1=document.quiz.question1.value;
      if (question1=="Yes"){
            correct++;
      }
    document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML="Score "+correct+" /10";
    }
```

I need to enter the value of number_correct into a txt document once a button is clicked on my html doc. Heres my PHP:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['number_correct']))
{
$data=$_POST['number_correct'];
$fp = fopen('results.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Heres my button:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="frm1" method="post">
       <input class="form-control" id="button" type="button"  value="Submit" onclick="check();"><br>

      <p methods="post" id="number_correct" name="number_correct">
  </p></form><
   </div>
```

My issue is that once the button is clicked and the value of number_correct is returned it is not written to reuslts.txt.

Comment: So what's the problem you're having?

Comment: Once clicked the result is not saved to a text file

Comment: No name attribute on your form elements

Answer (score -1):

```js
    let download = (stringContents, fileName) => {
        const blob = new Blob([stringContents], {type: 'application/json'});
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
    };

    let results = 'Congratulations! You got 9 questions right... out of 150 :(';
    download(results, 'results.txt');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, additional context would be ideal. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: It doesn’t even answer the question though